# How much bounty is on Riddick's head?

Tags: riddick, the-chronicles-of-riddick

I have seen Riddick and Chronicles of Riddick. And in both the movies we have seen that bounty hunters are behind him.

So I have a question about how much bounty is on Riddick's head.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It was **1.5 million.**

From [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0296572/trivia?item=tr2020108):

> When Riddick meets Tombs face to face, he asks what the bounty on his
>   head is priced at. Tombs first lies and says a million but is coaxed
>   into telling the truth of 1.5 million. 5 years prior, the price
>   displayed on Riddick's rap sheet in "Dark Fury" was roughly 1.1
>   million- so within 5 years, the bounty was raised about 400 grand.